# Missing weights file in kaggle notebook

Tags: kaggle

I was trying to train the DistilBert model on AG news dataset in kaggle by running this [code](https://www.kaggle.com/code/soumyaranjanpatel04/fork-of-notebooka959882591/notebook).
I created a version of the notebook and let it run in the background. After the training was done i was able to see a weights.h5 file in the output section of the notebook but when i tried to copy and edit the notebook and make further changes there was no weights.h5 file present anymore in the output section in the notebook.

[image: visible weights.h5]
[image: not visible]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a platform-specific (Kaggle) question, and OP should get better feedback by asking on that platform directly.